# Shell script prevent switching to other shell or escape from it

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting, zsh, sh

If in my automation script, I need to do something like install oh-my-zsh, I will have a .sh script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

runuser -l user -c 'sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"'
```

This works and will install oh-my-zsh as I expect but it then puts the session into a zsh shell. If I add the command `exit` to the end of the script, it does nothing.

How can I either disallow switching to zsh (Or any other shell) or exit from it in my script?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually look at this script you will see that, as the last thing it does, it calls:

```
    exec zsh -l
```

Just before that, you will see that it checks to see if the `RUNZSH` variable is set to `no`. If so, then it will simply exit without going into the shell.

So all you need to do is pass the environment variable `RUNZSH=no` to the command.

The comments at the top of the script contain other variables you can set and command line options you can use.